# Exclude exact string for a text field in JIRA filter

Tags: lucene, jira

I'm looking for a JIRA custom filter query to display tickets according criterias (e.g. status, priority or even a custom field). It should exclude an exact string from a text field

I already tried

```
"[Field name]" !~ "[Text to lookup]"
```

but this excludes also other tickets which have additional words than *[Text to lookup]* in the text field.

Example for keyword "*red*":

Show tickets with "*something red something other*" or "*red something else*" but hide all with just "*red*" in the desired field

Comment: did you talk about jira internals or about search via searchbox in jira?

Comment: I talked about creating a custom filter to display tickets according custom criterias (e.g. status or the one above)

Comment: I could easily search in Jira using minus notation, e.g. blah blah -red

Comment: That's exactly my problem: this hides all tickets which have the word "red" somewhere in the desired field. But I'm searching for something which hides just the tickets with exactly the word "red" in the field.

Example: show tickets with "something red something other" or "red something else" and hide all with "red" in the field

Comment: I've got your problem, could you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is issue/bug related to `comment !~`

I have ticket XY-234 with two comments. One comment contains string "abcde". Filter

```
(key = XY-234) AND (comment ~ "abcde")
```

return XY-234. But also both

```
(key = XY-234) AND (comment !~ "abcde")
```

and

```
(key = XY-234) AND (NOT (comment ~ "abcde"))
```

return XY-234.

Maybe it is not bug at all, but missing ANY/ALL feature

```
(key = XY-234) AND ( ALL(comment) !~ "abcde" )
```

?